# Self-updating application not running efficiently

Tags: python, while-loop, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, sleep

I have made a program that scrapes data from a webpage and gets the current bitcoin price (as well the index) and displays it on a label. For the price to update itself, I put the code inside an infinite while loop so it will continiously update itself. The problem I have is that it seems to use a lot of the cpu. I tried using time.sleep inside the while loop, but that made the program less responsive and more laggy. Here is the code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def bitcoinPrice():
    url = 'http://www.coindesk.com/price/'
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    btcPrice = soup.find('div', attrs=
    {'class' : 'bpi-value bpiUSD'}
                 )
    btcIndex = soup.find('span', attrs=
    {'class' : 'bpi-change changeUSD data-down'}
                     )
    return btcPrice.text + "(" + btcIndex.text + ")"



def bitcoinLabel():
    theLabel = Label(root, text = bitcoinPrice())
    theLabel.pack()
    while True:
        sleep(1)
        theLabel.configure(text = bitcoinPrice())
        root.update()


bitcoinLabel()
```

EDIT: I also noticed that whenever the price change, it flicks between the old value and new value for a couple of seconds before it displays the new value and stops "flicking". No idea why this is happening (not a big issue, just wanted to point that out).

Comment: change your sleep value: `sleep(0.1)` and see if that works.

Comment: What about using an API instead of scraping?  Check this one out: https://blockchain.info/api/exchange_rates_api

Comment: The stock was just an example. I will do some more scraping that needs data to be updated (not neccessarily stocks)